# Generate a Europass XML file from ModernCV

Tags: moderncv, europecv, europasscv

Is it possible to generate a Europass XML file from my [ModernCV](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) LaTeX document, in order to attach it to the resulting CV PDF file?

Using the online [Europass](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/) CV creation tool, I can generate the XML file and attach it separately to my ModernCV PDF output file. However, I would then need to keep track of two separate versions of my CV, which kind of defeats the whole purpose of using LaTeX for my CV to begin with. (The Europass CV creation tool is also capable of outputting a PDF file, containing the XML file.)

I have also considered using the [EuropassCV](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/europasscv) package instead of the ModernCV package. However, the EuropassCV package documentation makes no mention of an XML file, so I see no advantage over using ModernCV (other than for the looks then resembling the official Europass CV, if that is what you desire).

Of course, one could question the necessity of attaching a Europass XML file to ones CV. However, I imagine that some larger EU organisations, receiving thousands of applicants for each position, parse the XML file as a sort of 'first screening' of candidates. Hence, I would not rule out that a lack of XML file means lowering ones odds of being considered.

Comment: answer to the question in your first line is probably yes, but for those of us who have no idea what europass xml looks like, it would be simpler if you posted a small (fake) complete input document and showed what xml you want to generate

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'm sorry, I do not really know that much about XML or the specific implementation in this case (I was hoping some one else did). However, the XML format for the Europass CV is explained [here](http://interop.europass.cedefop.europa.eu/data-model/xml-resources/) while Europass example CVs, containing an embedded XML file, can be found [here](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/documents/curriculum-vitae/examples). The headings in the ModernCV would not differ much from the Europass CV, so essentially i would like the ModernCV to generate the same XML file as the EuropassCV.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: When I say 'the Europass CV' in my comment above, I refer to the [Europass CV generation tool](https://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/editors/en/cv/compose).